# Google Analytics Goal Funnel wrong results when Date Filter is Changed

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am facing issue in funnel visualization report. In my goal funnel visualization for step 1 for a specific date range, I see one of my page URLs as an exit.  But when I expand the date range filter, in the new funnel results, i don't see that particular  URL in the exits.

For example in the Dec 15, 2017 to Dec 18, 2017 date range, I see `abc.HTML` in the exits but for date range Dec 14, 2017 to Dec 18, 2017, I don't.

What is the reason for this discrepancy in the report or funnel view?

Comment: Differences such as this in Google Analytics are often caused by "sampling".    That is when GA bases the report on a percentage of your total traffic (a same of it) rather than on all your traffic.   GA reports usually say if they are sampled and say what the percent of traffic used is.   Does this report say that it is sampled?